# I have a 6 mile line that I need to make a point every 500 ft on it

Tags: arcgis-10.1

I have a 6 mile line that I need to make a point every 500 ft on it.  Any idea what tool I can use to do this?  I have arcmap 10.1 standard.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can also use the construct points tool from the "Editor" toolbar.

- Open the mxd which has your linear dataset.
- Then create a blank point dataset into which you would like the points to go into.
- Start an editing session on the point dataset.
- Select your line and then click on "Editor > Construct points"
  [image]

You will now see an option to add points at set distances along your line.
The units used here will be the same units as your mxd.

Comment: How do I create a follow up question to this about Arcgis Mobile?

Comment: I would suggest you post it as a new question, as you have already accepted an answer to this question. That way other users will be able to find your questions & answers if they have similar issues.

Answer (score 1):

In edit mode you can use the `Construct points...` tool, available under the Editor drop-down menu in the Editor toolbar.

You need a (empty) point shapefile as a target for the created points and your line. Define at which distance you want your points, the starting point etc.

Answer (score 0):

The [Densify-Tool](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//001v00000003000000) can be used to accomplish this. It´s available with Standard and Advanced License.